# What is causing a white screen when calling mysql from php/localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, localhost

Running windows 10, php 8.1.13, community mysql 8.0, localhost:8000 on mozilla firefox.

I'm new to web development, I'm trying to use mysql with php to maintain a user database for a website. I test my development on a php localhost run from the windows command prompt (php -S localhost:8000 -t  ) and then enter localhost:8000 as the URL in firefox. I've gotten lots of generic php code to run fine on localhost in this manner.

After downloading mysql, I'm able to successfully use procedural mysqli database instructions through php on the windows php shell. Through the php shell, I've created a mysql database with php, added simple entries with php, and then later retrieved them, so php is playing nicely with mysql.

Php is playing nicely with mozilla/localhost, and php shell is playing nicely with mysql, but when I try to combine the two processes (manipulate mysql database through a php server run as localhost) I just get a blank, white screen on firefox with no errors in the console or the terminal window.

The problem seems to happen almost immediately (this exact code executes fine (returns "success!") from the php shell window):

```
echo "test1";
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", $username, $password);
echo "test2";
if ($conn) 
{
  echo "success!";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
echo "test3";
```

conn appears to be declared OK. If I comment out the if statement then both test1, test2, and test3 echoes are visible, and I can close $conn. It's only when I actually try to DO anything with the connection (even this if statement) that the white screen appears.

Advice? Do I need to initialize the mysql server or something when run in this manner? Thanks!

I was expecting at minimum a relevant error message. The individual components work (A talks to B, B talks to C, so I expected A -> B -> C no problem.

Comment: Check the web server error log. Do a echo phpinfo(); to make sure you have libraries installed.

Comment: Are you seeing the requests displayed in the cmd window where you started the cli server? Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your script to see if any errors are generated.

Comment: @JasonK thanks so much for the response. phpinfo() confirms "Client API library version" = 8.1.10. I did now turn on the web server error log by turning display_errors = On
in php.ini, and ran it again. Thankfully at least now I see the fatal error: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant " " in C:\Users\warsa\github\rivalrealms\training\php_advanced.php:1099 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\warsa\github\rivalrealms\training\php_advanced.php on line 1099"  I'm not sure, however what the undefined constant " " could be. Will investigate: advice always appreciated.

Comment: @JasonK

Figured it out. This was weird. after "if ($conn)" there was a single character that visually appeared to be whitespace. However, the interpreter must have been reading it as <something else> (or maybe the carriage return was unusual somehow). Replacing the <not-a-whitespace> with an <actual whitespace> (or with nothing) resolved my problem. Ever see that before?

Comment: @nnichols thanks, I did set those flags initially, but I wasn't correctly outputting the error messages to the server log so it didn't matter. Figured out the problem anyways.

Comment: how do I mark this issue as resolved? Or is that not something that is done?

Comment: You can just delete the question.